# Open a modal populated with table values when a table row is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the piece of pure HTML + PHP code below (no bootstrap, no laravel) that creates a table and populates it with the results of a REST API consumption.

I want to be able to open a modal when the row is mouse-clicked with the values from the specific line that was clicked populated into text boxes. What am I missing?

```html
<html>
<script>
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
    rows.forEach(row => {
      row.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const column1 = this.cells[0].innerText;
        const column2 = this.cells[1].innerText;
        const column3 = this.cells[2].innerText;

        const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        modal.style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("modal-column1").value = column1;
        document.getElementById("modal-column2").value = column2;
        document.getElementById("modal-column3").value = column3;
      });
    });

  const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close");
        closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
    });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
      #myModal {
       display: block;
       position: fixed; 
       z-index: 1; 
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%; 
       height: 100%; 
       overflow: auto; 
       background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
      }
    
      .modal-content {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 100px auto;
      }
      .close {
        color: #333;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      p {
        margin: 10px 0;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

</style>
<body>
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column1</th>
          <th>Column2</th>
          <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php 
          // ignore the PHP PART, it's just an example of how the table is populated (but my actual code works for the API consumption)

                foreach($v[...] as $k[...]=>$v[...]) {
                  echo '<tr><td>';
                  echo $v3['data'];
                 [...]
                }
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
?>

 </tbody>
 </table>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>
      <label for="modal-column1">Column1:</label>
      <input type="text" id="modal-column1" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="modal-column2">Column2:</label>
      <input type="text" id="modal-column2" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="modal-column3">Column3:</label>
      <input type="text" id="modal-column3" readonly>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're probably trying to attach listeners to the rows before they actually exist in the page. Js runs immediately when a script block is found by the browser. Yours is above all the other code, so it'll run first, before the browser has even created the other elements. Either move it to the end or wrap the code in a DomContentLoaded event handler

Comment: Ok, moved the <script> tag to the bottom of the document (after the </div> tags) however the modal still won't open when the line/row is clicked. If I change the display attribute of #myModal style to "block" it appears but then it won't close, and if I change it to "none" then it won't open. I'm really missing some point here. (Thanks anyway)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem maybe, but there’s an HTML-native modal called `<dialog>` that has built-in show, showModal and close events that you might find helpful. [Demo](https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/KKBJbmO) and [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the JS code after the  tags like @jonrsharpe suggested but that didn't worked all alone, so I had to also change the JS code to look like this (and it worked like a charm):

```
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  var span = document.getElementById("close");

  function openModal(row) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("modal-column1").value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("modal-column2").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("modal-column3").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
  }

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

</script>
```